# Why is this python while loop not ending?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am wondering why this code seems to loop infinitely? The logic, `while not False = while True`, and this True is referring to `100 < 0` which is false, hence it should execute the print statement instead, right? Why is it stuck in the loop then..?

```
num = 100
while not False:
    if num < 0:
        break
print('num is: ' + str(num))
```

Comment: Do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and figure out how `num` could ever become smaller than zero (which is the only condition you have to break the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` statement is outside the while loop. You have to use an `else` clause with the `if`.

```
num = 100
while not False:
    if num < 0:
        break
    else:
        print('num is: ' + str(num))
        # Do something with num to decrease it, else it will stay a forever loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

a `while` statement should be proceeded with a conditional. The conditional `True` (or in your cause `not False`) always evaluates to `True` so the loop never ends.

the `if` block is never executed because because `num < 0` never evaluates to `True`. Did you mean to decrement num by 1 in each iteration of the `while` block? If so, add a `num = num - 1` within the `while` block:

```
num = 100
while not False:
    if num < 0:
        break
    num = num - 1
print('num is: ' + str(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Since the following is not true, the contents of your `if` clause will not be evaluated, hence the `break` is not performed.

```
if num < 0:
```

All that is really running is the following:

```
num = 100
while not False:
    if num < 0: #False
        #what is here is unimportant, since it will never run anyway.
```

...or to simplify it "all the way", this is what you're doing:

```
while true:
    if false:
        break
```